# How to retrieve a content of Alfresco workflow?

Tags: javascript, alfresco, activiti

I have a workflow where I have audio content. I need to access for this content in other application (with javascript). I am trying with a GET method to this URL:

http://localhost:8086/alfresco/service/cmis/s/SpacesStore/i/1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a/children?alf_ticket=TICKET_f9906d69befbc49668b92ddf372d62532a29ce7d

(In this URL, the id "1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a" is the identificator of the package of the workflow task.)

But, the response is the next XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/" xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/" xmlns:alf="http://www.alfresco.org" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<author><name>admin</name></author>
<generator version="4.2.0 (r56674-b4848)">Alfresco (Community)</generator>
<icon>http://localhost:8086/alfresco/images/logo/AlfrescoLogo16.ico</icon>
<id>urn:uuid:1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a-children</id>
<link rel="service" href="http://localhost:8086/alfresco/service/cmis"/>
<link rel="self" href="http://localhost:8086/alfresco/service/cmis/s/SpacesStore/i/1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a/children?alf_ticket=TICKET_f9906d69befbc49668b92ddf372d62532a29ce7d"/>
<link rel="via" href="http://localhost:8086/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a"/>
<link rel="up" href="http://localhost:8086/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/13dd8d00-4ccd-4894-87fc-0b055cf41a4b/children" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"/>
<link rel="down" href="http://localhost:8086/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a/descendants" type="application/cmistree+xml"/>
<link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/foldertree" href="http://localhost:8086/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a/tree" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"/>
<title>1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a Children</title>
<updated>2015-05-27T11:18:13.600-04:00</updated>
<opensearch:totalResults>0</opensearch:totalResults>
<opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
<opensearch:itemsPerPage>-1</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
<cmisra:numItems>0</cmisra:numItems>
</feed>
```

I don't know how to use this XML for my purpose. I need to hear the content (mp3 audio file) and modify its properties in my custom application.

Also I am trying with the next URL (GET):

http://localhost:8086/alfresco/service/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a

But the result is: **Web Script Status 404 - Not Found**

How to retrieve a content of a workflow? There is some RESTful URL for this ?

Thanks for any help.

Greetings,
Pablo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolve my questions using other RESTful URL. So, the steps to retrieve a content of a workflow is the next:

**1. I get the package ID (this is a folder node) of the task of workflow:**

*GET /alfresco/service/api/task-instances/activiti$taskID*

```
{
   "data": 
      {
         "id": "activiti$taskID",
         "url": "api\/task-instances\/activiti$taskID",
         "name": "wf:taskName",
         "title": "Task for this",
         "description": "Hello World !",
         "state": "IN_PROGRESS",
         "path": "api\/workflow-paths\/activiti$workflowID",
         "isPooled": false,
         "isEditable": true,
         "isReassignable": true,
         "isClaimable": false,
         "isReleasable": false,
         "outcome": null,
         "owner":
         {
            "userName": "admin",
            "firstName": "Admin",
            "lastName": "istrator"
         },
         "properties":
         {
            "bpm_percentComplete": 0,
            "bpm_description": "Hello World !",
            "bpm_hiddenTransitions": [],
            "bpm_package":"workspace:\/\/SpacesStore\/1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a",
       ...........................................................
}
```

So, the package ID is: **1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a**

**2. With the package ID, I get the content which I need of this package:**

*GET /alfresco/service/slingshot/node/workspace/SpacesStore/1a7be6f8-0c50-4995-a211-1736642db06a*

```
.............................................    
"children": [
      {
         "name": {
            "name": "{http:\/\/www.alfresco.org\/model\/content\/1.0}grabacion1.mp3",
            "prefixedName": "cm:grabacion1.mp3"
        },
         "nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/9ed7905d-7017-40e9-9514-93244b0a9a6a",
         "type": {
            "name": "{http:\/\/www.alfresco.org\/model\/content\/1.0}content",
            "prefixedName": "cm:content"
        },
         "assocType": {
            "name": "{http:\/\/www.alfresco.org\/model\/bpm\/1.0}packageContains",
            "prefixedName": "bpm:packageContains"
        },
         "primary": false,
         "index": 0
      }
   ],
.............................................
```

So, the content ID is: **9ed7905d-7017-40e9-9514-93244b0a9a6a**

**3. Finally, I get the content which I need:**

*GET /alfresco/service/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/9ed7905d-7017-40e9-9514-93244b0a9a6a*

If you need access to the properties of the content, you can use the URL of the step two with the content ID (in this example: 9ed7905d-7017-40e9-9514-93244b0a9a6a).

Greetings :)